# Reducing power consumption of Bluetooth server (accept)

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am interfacing with a Bluetooth embedded device, and I want it to reconnect automatically when android phone is in reach. So far got it working with couple of issues. What I also noticed is that while phone is blocked on accept() call to the socket, it still consumes quite a bit of power. Nothing to compare with the Car speaker phone for example that does not seem to influence battery much. I was wondering if people have any trick to be more power friendly?

Also, currently the accept works on the AcceptThread.run (as in the Bluetooth Chat example), but not in a service. Should I move it to one? Any pointer to how to do accept in a service and move it to thread/activity will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The accept (AcceptThread) code will be exactly the same whether it is in a service or an activity/Application.  Whether you should move it into a service depends on whether you need it to keep running after the app closes.  If you don't need to move it to a service then don't bother because it makes your app's structure and life-cycle a little more complicated.

I'm rather surprised at your observation that the accept causes increased power consumption.  When you create a socket and call accept on it then Android adds your UUID to the list of available Bluetooth services - it doesn't put the Bluetooth radio into a different mode, so why would it cause increased power consumption?

Comment: I too do not know why is causes more power drain... but apparently I am not alone: http://farwestab.wordpress.com/tag/serial-port-profile/